# Syntax Error : SQL update with count and inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
ticketId integer not null,
eventId integer not null,
ticketUsed integer, 
userName text not null,
FOREIGN KEY (ticketId) REFERENCES ticketType (ticketId)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE ticketType ( 
eventId integer not null, 
ticketId integer unique not null,
ticketsUsed integer,
FOREIGN KEY (eventId) REFERENCES event (eventId)
);
```

I'm trying to update `ticketType.ticketsUsed` according to used tickets

```
UPDATE ticketType 
SET ticketsUsed = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user as u WHERE ticketUsed=1)
WHERE ticketId = u.ticketId;
```

But I get an error:

> Error: no such column: u.ticketId

```
UPDATE ticketType
SET ticketsUsed = us.count
FROM ticketType
INNER JOIN (SELECT ticketId, COUNT(*) as count FROM user  WHERE ticketUsed=1 group by ticketId) us 
ON us.ticketId=ticketType.ticketId
WHERE eventId = 23779;
```

> Error: near "FROM": syntax error

Comment: "as u" should come after the sub query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `ticketId` filter inside the subquery:

```
UPDATE ticketType
SET ticketsUsed = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM user AS u
                   WHERE ticketUsed = 1
                     AND u.ticketId = ticketType.ticketId)
```